# Is the sum of the tensor product of a linear operator, the tensor of the sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

According to the notes I'm working from

$$ \sum_{y\in \mathbf{B}_{M},z \in \mathbf{B}_{M}}\big(\left|z\right>\!\!\left<z\right|\otimes\left|y\oplus f(z)\right>\!\!\left<y\right|\big) \stackrel{?}{=}  I_M\otimes\sum_{y\in \mathbf{B}_{M},z \in \mathbf{B}_{M}}\big(\left|y\oplus f(z)\right>\!\!\left<y\right|\big)$$

where $\mathbf{B}_{M}$ is the basis of an $M$-dimensional vector space.

But I'm struggling to get this result. I can get as far as

$$ \sum_{y\in \mathbf{B}_{M},z \in \mathbf{B}_{M}}\big(\left|z\right>\!\!\left<z\right|\otimes\left|y\oplus f(z)\right>\!\!\left<y\right|\big) =  \sum_{z \in \mathbf{B}_{M}}\left(\left|z\right>\!\!\left<z\right|\otimes\left[\sum_{y\in \mathbf{B}_{M}}\left|y\oplus f(z)\right>\!\!\left<y\right|\right]\right)$$
which I think is correct; but then I'm stuck.

Have I got this wrong? What properties of the tensor product of linear operators account for the result I expect (if indeed it is correct)?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you re-write the subscripts appropriately, the obvious thing to expect is 
$$
\left( \sum_{i \in I} A_i \right) \otimes \left( \sum_{j \in J} B_j \right) = \sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} A_i \otimes B_j. 
$$
By linearity of the tensor product this holds if $I$ and $J$ are finite. Equality $I=J$ is not necessarily. This is just the fact that $A \otimes (B+C) = A \otimes B + A \otimes C$. In particular your conjecture was not quite correct.

Comment: Yes, that gets me started. Can you elaborate a bit (see added example, were I've messed up the subscripts a bit too).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius : I don't understand the bra-ket notation. All I can say is that you can apply the linearity property "one side at a time", i.e. 
$$
A \otimes \left(\sum_{j \in J} B_j \right) = \sum_{j \in J} A \otimes B_j, \quad \left( \sum_{i \in I} A_i \right) \otimes B = \sum_{i \in I} A_i \otimes B. 
$$
Perhaps a place to start would be to split the sum $\sum_{y,z}$ by writing $\sum_y \sum_z$ so you can move both of them around.

Comment: That helps! What I'm stuck on is that the form of my example is $ \sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{z\in Z}A(z)\otimes B(y,z)$, so while that gets me to $ \sum_{z\in Z}A(z)\otimes \sum_{y\in Y}B(y,z)$ which for my $A(z)$ is indeed $ I\otimes \sum_{y\in Y}B(y,z)$, that leaves the $z$ in the second term orphaned.

Comment: I see. The key thing is simply that $A \otimes (B+C) = A \otimes B + A \otimes C$, which just follows from the definitions of $A\otimes B$ and $A+B$. I think.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius : Exactly! The rest is just induction on the number of terms and applying the same reasoning on the first factor instead of the second.

Comment: Yes, I was getting lost (summations are a bane) and confused by the apparent use of two indices in the second term, which is irrelevant.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand how this applies to my case. The thing I was stuck on was the indices (which are just counters, not arguments). What I've got is $\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{z\in Z}[A(z)\otimes B(y,z)]$ which is $[\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{z\in Z}A(z)]\otimes [\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{z\in Z}B(y,z)]$ or $[\sum_{z\in Z}A(z)]\otimes [\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{z\in Z}B(y,z)]$. Is that right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius : no, you're allowed to "pull sums in", which means they cannot still be there in the front when you pull them in. Both your equations are incorrect. Pull in one sum at a time!

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I don't see it them. Can you spell out in an edit to your answer how $\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{z\in Z}[A(z)\otimes B(y,z)]$ would end up with as $[\sum_{z\in Z}A(z)]\otimes C$. And what would $C$ be (in my case in the question its $I$?

Comment: The only thing you can do is pull in the $y$-sum because the $z$ is a variable in both arguments. To be able to pull a sum in (in the first argument for instance), the second argument must not depend on that subscript. In other words, $A \otimes B_1 + A \otimes B_2 = A \otimes (B_1 \otimes B_2)$ because both terms have $A$ as the left factor ; if they were different, there would be nothing to factor out.

Comment: So that gets me to $\sum_{z\in Z}[A(z)\otimes \sum_{y\in Y}B(y,z)]$, and I need to get from there to $[\sum_{z\in Z}A(z)]\otimes C$ for some $C$. That's the crux of the question I'm asking.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius : then either the question is wrong (which I hope for you is not the case) or you need more than just linearity to come to the conclusion! Sorry I can't be more of help.

Comment: I've edited the question.